# Can two external displays be driven from one Thunderbolt port?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I have the new MacBook Air which only has a Thunderbolt output (no HDMI or DVI) and I have 2 external monitors. How can I get this all hooked up (at the lowest cost, if possible)?

EDIT:
After using the DualHead2Go ME, I'm half-satisfied; it does split my single external port into 2 DVIs, but the externals act as 1 with double the width, so the resolution is very off and weird to look at. Looking back I probably should have bought the Pro to support both of my externals, but with my current Air this is the best I can do for 2 externals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Apple's [display adapters](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/mac_accessories/displays) will let you connect one of these external monitors, there's also the [Matrox DualHead2Go Digital ME](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_me/) which will connect two external DVI displays (I've never seen or used one, ymmv).

Comment: You should be aware that the displays need to be the same resolution for the Matrox DualHead solutions to work.

Comment: ...and both the same orientation, i presume? nuts :(

Comment: theyre actually identical asus 23" monitors :)

Comment: @username Probably.

Comment: This is an old question, but I really must advise against using the DH2G's. My employer purchased a whole stack of them for the mac users, and every single one was dead within a year.

Answer (score 1):

The current-generation MacBook Air's integrated graphics only supports one external display.

Further, there are no products that I know of that are shipping (as of when I answered this) that can "split" a Thunderbolt signal to connect two non-Thunderbolt displays. The only way I know of to connect multiple displays to a Thunderbolt Mac via Thunderbolt is to use Apple's Thunderbolt Display.

You could use one of the various DisplayLink products to connect one of your displays via USB and use a plain mini DisplayPort adapter for the other display (this would connect to your Thunderbolt port).

Answer (score 1):

Zotac provides an adapter to split a regular or mini DisplayPort into two HDMI ports. It's the ZT-DP2HD (DisplayPort) or ZT-MDP2HD (mini DisplayPort). Anandtech has a brief blurb about it [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4563/zotac-releases-displayport-to-dual-hdmi-adapter). For $50, I think it's worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with the splitter of 1 thunderbolt to 2 display ports is that the monitors will be mirrored, they won't be extended desktop. With Mac Air I had to use the thunderbolt for monitor 1 and the usb for monitor 2 in order to have extended desktop.

Another annoyance is that, for example, if you have a large spreadsheet, you wont be able to see it using both monitors.

If you really need a full extended desktop, you will need 2 thunderbolt ports.

Answer (score -2):

If you have monitors that have DisplayPorts, you should be able to go from the MacBook Air to DisplayPort, and then DisplayPort out on one monitor to the other one.

This is DisplayPort 2.0 or 2.1 I think.

Comment: Daisy chaining is not possible with DisplayPort, only Thunderbolt.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect information. DisplayPort IS DAISYCHAINING soloution. You should review specification more carefulkly: http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/ It is not Thunderbolt that allows daisyxchaining. However to my understanding problem is that with these two standards you cannot daisychain one and then another and then again.

Comment: @wst daisy chaining is possible over DP MST, but MacOS doesn't support MST in this mode.

Answer (score -2):

Belkin Dual View Mini DisplayPort to 2X DVI Adapter Dongle ([F2CD060](https://goo.gl/CcHqWk)) $60...all you need

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: Are you sure you want to recommend that product?  I searched it on Amazon (provided you the link) and it's not highly rated.  You might want to reconsider unless you have some personal experience.