# Connecting 2 external displays to 1 port on my Macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

Have a macbook pro with Intel HD 4000 graphics card.

Right now, I connect two external Dell monitors, with each monitor going to a separate thunderbolt port.

It is a pain to connect both of these of these every day, and I can get their order mixed up sometimes. Is there any solution that would allow me to just plug in one thing to connect my external monitors?

I saw the DualHead2Go Digital ME does this, but at a steep price, what are some other options?

Related question: [Can two external displays be driven from one Thunderbolt port?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61920/can-two-external-displays-be-driven-from-one-thunderbolt-port)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can two external displays be driven from one Thunderbolt port?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61920/can-two-external-displays-be-driven-from-one-thunderbolt-port)

Comment: I think the unique question here is "Is there any solution that would allow me to just plug in one thing to connect my external monitors?"

Answer (score 1):

My 2011 MacBook Pro has only a single DisplayPort connector which drives a 24" external monitor, then I use a USB to DVI converter and connect two additional 24" external monitors for a total of three external monitors. The DisplayPort monitor is fast, while the two USB to DVI converter monitors are much slower but sufficient for email and web browsing tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has used options that are a little less for the DualHead2Go Digital ME and some other Matrox devices that might work (though all of those are in the $200 range).

There is also the Belkin Thunderbolt Express Dock which has two thunderbolt ports along with misc other ports for $149

It looks like Thunderbolt splitting is relatively expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The three options that come to mind here that don't have significant costs:

1. Purchase a USB-to-[your monitor connection type] converter; while it won't work as well as the direct Thunderbolt connection, you will now have different connections to your machine for each of your monitors, and be unable to mix them up.
2. Label your Thunderbolt adapters. (Front/Back, for example)
3. Tape the plastic portions of your Thunderbolt connectors together, with a piece of foam or plastic in between to maintain distance between the two connectors, rigging the two Thunderbolt adapters to be (functionally) a single connector.

Personally, a dock is probably your best bet; though expensive, they would take care of this quickly. (and, there's a decent variety of options if you look around)